# Extracting information from loaded excel files

Tags: reporting

Is there any way to automatically extract information from excel files that are loaded as documents in salesforce?  The excel file that is loaded contains numerous tabs and we are looking to export the information out of the excel file into a separate database so we can use the data for further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I know of that *might* do what you're asking is [Apptus X-Author for Excel](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5P76EAF) which is available on the App Exchange. I know it's very powerful for sending data between Excel and Salesforce when it comes to standard & custom objects. Whether it will do that with Excel files stored in Salesforce, I don't know, but if there's anything out there that can do it, X-Author would be the most likely "out of the box" solution you'd be able to find.